# Mismatch between response data on client, server?

Tags: node.js, json, response, fetch-api

I have the following in a vanilla node server:

```
const respond = ({ res, data = "", contentType = CONTENT_TYPE.html, statusCode = 200 }) => {
  // console.log("responding with data: ", data) // <-- custom message appears here
  res.writeHead(statusCode, {
    "Content-Type": contentType,
    "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(data)
  })
  res.end(data)
}

handleRequest = (req, res) => {
  respond({res, data: JSON.stringify({ message: "custom message" }), contentType: CONTENT_TYPE.json })
}
```

But on the client, the parsed response does not contain the custom message

```
fetch(...)
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json) // { message: "success" }
  })
```

1. where is `{ message: "success" }` even coming from
2. how can I access the message I tried to send?

(FWIW network tab in dev tools shows that the response payload was also this generic `{ message: "success" }`...)

Comment: FWIW also it's a POST request from the client, but I didn't think that would matter

Comment: is it really necessary to stringify the response, once you set the content type JSON?

Comment: @LuizFernandodaSilva not sure but the same behavior happens client-side with or without that stringify

Answer (score 0):

yea so later on in my code I actually called `respond` with `{ message: success }` :facepalm: